# How do I convert my 5GB 1 liner file to lines based on pattern?

Tags: unix

I have a 5GB 1 liner file with JSON data and each line starts from this pattern "{"created". I need to be able to use Unix commands on my Mac to convert this monster of a 1 liner into as many lines as it deserves. Any commands?

```
ASCII English text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

Comment: Please post an example from the file so that others may offer specific answers.  (e.g. The file has a line that looks like '{"created":"yesterday","contents":"tea"}{"created":"today","contents":"coffee"}' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough memory you can open the file once with the TextWrangler application (the free BBEdit cousin) and use regular search/replace on the whole file. Use \r in replace to add a return. Will be very slow at opening the file, may even hang if low on memory, but in the end it may probably work. No scripting, no commands,.. etc.. I did this with big SQL files and sometimes it did the job.

You have to replace your line-start string with the same string with \n or \r or \r\n in front of it.

Comment: I have the file open on Hexfiend and it has a replace function. remember, i don't want the  newline character to be in the file, just the lines, or else my parser in java will have issues. How would I do it then?

Comment: @user3575840 I don't understand "i don't want the newline character to be in the file". There is no "lines" without a newline (or return) char! On the Mac you must have \r (return), on Windows you have "\r\n" (return + new line)

Comment: You are right. Basically its a tweet json file and there are two 'created at', for instance, someone retweeted, so his 'created at' and then the retweet's 'created at'. How would that work. Also, each line ends with 'lang:name', but not all languages end with same name so ?

Comment: @user3575840 I think you have to clarify with yourself about what you want to do and what the problem is, asking yourself the question. Have you heard of "Ask The Duck debugging"? hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html (it is real, not a joke!). Anyway it may be hierarchical, like this { ... replies: {... replies:...}} anyway adding newlines after and before { and } would help understanding

Answer (score 0):

Unclear how it can be a “one liner” file but then each line starts with `"{"created"`, but perhaps `python -mjson.tool` can help you get started:

```
cat your_source_file.json | python -mjson.tool > nicely_formatted_file.json
```

Piping raw JSON through ``python -mjson.tool` will cleanly format the JSON to be more human readable. More info [here](http://www.skorks.com/2013/04/the-best-way-to-pretty-print-json-on-the-command-line/).

Comment: Each JSON is one line, they are tweets. But this time, millions of tweets are on 1 line, hence the weird factor. I think I changed the file format from .txt to .json and that did it. even though my smaller 64MB example tweets file remains intact and works. Anyway your code gives me an error: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 20001 column 1 (char 4743 - 69430537)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP as a shell command (if PHP is installed), just save a text file with name "myscript" and appropriate code (I cannot test code now, but the idea is as follows)

**UNTESTED CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

    $REPLACE_STRING='{"created'; // anything you like


    // open input file with fopen() in read mode
    $inFp=fopen('big_in_file.txt', "r");

    // open output file with fopen() in write mode
    $outFp=fopen('big_out_file.txt', "w+");


// while not end of file
while (!feof($inFp)) {

    // read file chunks here with fread() in variable $chunk
    $chunk = fread($inFp, 8192);

    // do a $chunk=str_replace($REPLACE_STRING,"\r".$REPLACE_STRING; // to add returns
    // (or use \r\n for windows end of lines)

    $chunk=str_replace($REPLACE_STRING,"\r".$REPLACE_STRING,$chunk);

    // problem: if chunk contains half the string at the end
    // easily solved if $REPLACE_STRING is a one char like '{'
    // otherwise test for fist char { in the end of $chunk
    // remove final part and save it in a var for nest iteration


    // write $chunk to output file
    fwrite($outFp, $chunk);

// End while
}

?>
```

After you save it you must make it executable whith sudo chmod a+x ./myscript

and then launch it as ./myscript in terminal

After this, the myscript file is a full unix command

Comment: @user3575840 why? The code is untested but the approach to modify big files is correct (you read 8KB chunks and save 8KB chunks, one by one, adding newlines where needed)

Answer (score 0):

OS X ships with both flex and bison, you can use those to write a parser for your data.

Comment: I just need to break the file into lines. :)

Comment: Post some examples of the data you have.